# Port Forwarding - Reverse SSH - Source IP

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall

Scenario :

I have to host a Webserver/SSH server at "Server B" which is without public IP,

I purchased a VPS "Server A" with a public IP and I am doing reverse SSH port forwarding as

```
Internet -->  22 : "Server A" --> 22  : Server B
Internet --> 443 : "Server A" --> 443 : Server B
```

So accessing "Server A" at port 22 forwards to "Server B" at port 22 as expected

Problem:

I cant see the source IP accessed at "Server B" , I just see the source IP as localhost, Due to regular brute forcing attacks at SSH , I need fail2ban at "server B' but that has been useless because of no source IP.

I cannot change the port from 22 to something else.

I have tried VPN from "Server B" to "Server A" but I couldn't setup the iptables rules at "Server A" to forward a specific port from "Server A" to "Server B".

What could I do best so that I can get the source IP at "Server B" ?

Thanks.

Comment: So server A and server B are in the same network? If server B does not have a public IP then all the SSH connections must be coming from the local network not the internet. And if someone if port forwarding to server B from server A over the internet you need fail2ban on server A instead of B

Answer (score 1):

```
Server-A = Private IP 192.168.1.1 with Public IP 1.2.3.4 (has direct internet access)
Server-B = 192.168.1.2 (no direct internet access)
Client-PC = Public IP 5.6.7.8  (router's ISP address)
```

You must get rid of SSH Tunneling in order to achieve your goal. When `Client-PC` attempts to connect to `Server-A`, it must be redirected to `Server-B` on `TCP 22`. From `Server-B` perspective, SSH traffic is coming from `5.6.7.8`

On the host that is acting as a Linux gateway (Server-A in this case), do the following:

```
$ sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:22
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

From `Server-B`, make sure it knows how to send return traffic back to `5.6.7.8`

If not, then add a static route on `Server-B`

```
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```